# I need to run GnuTLS with X509 in Server/Client (doubts and needs fixing)

Tags: ssl, networking, openssl, gnutls

GnuTLS suffered drastic changes as I see in the examples mentioned in the following websites with respect to my version of code that previously worked based on almost the same examples as before:

- [Echo server with X.509 authentication](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Echo-server-with-X_002e509-authentication.html#Echo-server-with-X_002e509-authentication)
- [Client example with X.509 certificate support](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Client-example-with-X_002e509-certificate-support.html#Client-example-with-X_002e509-certificate-support)

the problem is that before you had to use the authority certificate for the client program, now you need the certificate and the key that was only used on the server side. What is this drastic change? In the end which side belongs as private and public among the generated certificates? (according to the example, I have to replace `gnutls_certificate_set_x509_trust_file` by `gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key_file`)

What are the lines with the parameters for the openssl command that I have to use to generate all the necessary certificates in this example of Server and Client?

It is also very confusing the issue of the file names for the generated certificates, sometimes it is .pem and sometimes .crt/.key, tell you how I should create these names exactly (if you think some of this is wrong).

Because of the updates of GnuTLS it has stopped working and now the Handshake fails, causing the server to fail the handshake and in the client continue believing that the connection is fine.

this is the code:

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>

int main(){
  const char*txterr;
  int lsck;
  gnutls_certificate_credentials_t xcred;
  gnutls_priority_t pcache;
  gnutls_session_t sesion;
  sockaddr_in _cli;

  //INICIO GLOBAL
  //if(!gnutls_check_version("3.6.15"))return -1;
  if(!gnutls_check_version("3.5.10"))return -1;
  if(gnutls_global_init()<0)return -2;
  if(gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials(&xcred)<0)return -3;
  if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_trust_file(xcred,"cert/ca.crt",GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)<0)return -4;
  //if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_crl_file(xcred,"cert/revocar.crl",GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)<0)return -5;
  if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key_file(
    xcred,"cert/serv.crt","cert/serv.key",GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)<0)return -6;
  //if(gnutls_certificate_set_ocsp_status_request_file(xcred,"reqocsp.der",0)<0)return -4;
  if(gnutls_priority_init(&pcache,"PERFORMANCE:%SERVER_PRECEDENCE",&txterr)<0){printf("TLS: %s\n",txterr);return -7;}
  if(gnutls_certificate_set_known_dh_params(xcred,GNUTLS_SEC_PARAM_MEDIUM)<0)return -8;

  //ABRE PUERTO SERVIDOR
  lsck=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(lsck==-1){lsck=0;printf("Imposible usar Puerto\n");return -1;}
  {int optval=1;setsockopt(lsck,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(void*)&optval,sizeof(int));}
  //Convierte el puerto en Escucha
  {
    struct sockaddr_in dsrv;
    dsrv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    dsrv.sin_port=htons(9080);
    dsrv.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(lsck,(struct sockaddr*)&dsrv,sizeof(dsrv))!=0)
      {printf("Imposible bindear Puerto\n");return -2;}
    if(listen(lsck,10)!=0)
      {printf("Imposible abrir Puerto\n");return -3;}
  }
  printf("Abriendo Puerto\n");

  //ESCUCHA PUERTO
  if(gnutls_init(&sesion,GNUTLS_SERVER)<0)return -6;
  if(gnutls_priority_set(sesion,pcache)<0)return -6;
  if(gnutls_credentials_set(sesion,GNUTLS_CRD_CERTIFICATE,xcred)<0)return -6;
  gnutls_certificate_server_set_request(sesion,GNUTLS_CERT_IGNORE);
  gnutls_handshake_set_timeout(sesion,GNUTLS_DEFAULT_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT);
  int _scli=sizeof(sockaddr_in);
  int nsck=accept(lsck,(sockaddr*)&_cli,(socklen_t*)&_scli);
  if(nsck<0)return -3;
  gnutls_transport_set_int(sesion,nsck);
  int tm;
  do{
    tm=gnutls_handshake(sesion);
  }while(tm<0&&gnutls_error_is_fatal(tm)==0);
  if(tm<0){close(nsck);gnutls_deinit(sesion);return -6;}
  printf("Entrando Usuario: %x:%d\n",_cli.sin_addr,_cli.sin_port);

  //CIFRA PUERTO CLIENTE
  gnutls_datum_t out;
  gnutls_session_t tls_sesion;
  if(gnutls_init(&tls_sesion,GNUTLS_CLIENT)<0)return -6;
  if(gnutls_server_name_set(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_NAME_DNS,"blackrook.ddns.net",strlen("blackrook.ddns.net"))<0)return -7;
  if(gnutls_set_default_priority(tls_sesion)<0)return -8;
  int ret=gnutls_priority_set_direct(tls_sesion,"NORMAL",&txterr);
  if(ret<0){
    switch(ret){
    case GNUTLS_E_INVALID_REQUEST:
      printf("Error tipo %s\n",txterr);
      return -9;
    }
  }
  if(gnutls_credentials_set(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_CRD_CERTIFICATE,xcred)<0)return -10;
  gnutls_session_set_verify_cert(tls_sesion,"blackrook.ddns.net",0);
  //Toma el FD Socket
  gnutls_transport_set_int(tls_sesion,nsck);
  gnutls_handshake_set_timeout(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_DEFAULT_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT);
  do{ret=gnutls_handshake(tls_sesion);
  }while(ret<0&&!gnutls_error_is_fatal(ret));
  if(ret<0){
    gnutls_certificate_type_t type;
    int status;
    switch(ret){
    case GNUTLS_E_CERTIFICATE_VERIFICATION_ERROR:
      type=gnutls_certificate_type_get(tls_sesion);
      status=gnutls_session_get_verify_cert_status(tls_sesion);
      if(gnutls_certificate_verification_status_print(status,type,&out,0)<0)return -255;
      printf("TLS: cert verify output: %s\n",out.data);
      gnutls_free(out.data);
    }
    printf("TLS: Handshake fallado: %s\n",gnutls_strerror(ret));
    return -11;
  }{
    char*desc=gnutls_session_get_desc(tls_sesion);
    printf("TLS: Session info: %s\n",desc);
    gnutls_free(desc);
  }
  //Envia mensaje cifrado
  char*msg="Este es canal abierto.";
  gnutls_record_send(tls_sesion,msg,strlen(msg)+1);

  //CIERRA
  if(gnutls_bye(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_SHUT_WR)<0)printf("TLS: Falla cerrando\n");
  close(nsck);
  gnutls_deinit(tls_sesion);
  close(lsck);
  gnutls_certificate_free_credentials(xcred);
  gnutls_priority_deinit(pcache);
  gnutls_global_deinit();

  return 0;
}
```

Cliente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>

int main(){
  int fd;
  const char*txterr;
  gnutls_certificate_credentials_t xcred;
  gnutls_session_t tls_sesion;

  //INICIA TLS
  if(!gnutls_check_version("3.5.10"))return -1;
  if(gnutls_global_init()<0)return -2;
  if(gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials(&xcred)<0)return -3;
  if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_system_trust(xcred)<0)return -4;
  if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_trust_file(xcred,"cert/ca.crt",GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)<0)return -5;
  //if(gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key_file(xcred,"cert/cert.pem","cert/key.pem",GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM)<0)return -5;

  //ABRE SOCKET
  fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(fd==-1){printf("Imposible abrir nuevo E/S\n");return -1;}
  struct addrinfo hints,*serv,*p;
  char*zip="blackrook.ddns.net",*zprt="9080";
  memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
  int i,ip;
  if(i=getaddrinfo(zip,zprt,&hints,&serv)){
    printf("Conexion no establecida\n");return 0;}
  for(p=serv;p!=0;p=p->ai_next){
    if(p->ai_addr->sa_family==AF_INET){
      ip=((struct sockaddr_in*)p->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
      if(connect(fd,p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen)==-1)continue;
      freeaddrinfo(serv);
      printf("Conexion establecida\n");goto JmpConti;
    }
  }freeaddrinfo(serv);printf("Conexion no establecida2\n");return 0;
JmpConti:

  //CIFRA PUERTO
  gnutls_datum_t out;
  if(gnutls_init(&tls_sesion,GNUTLS_CLIENT)<0)return -6;
  if(gnutls_server_name_set(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_NAME_DNS,"blackrook.ddns.net",strlen("blackrook.ddns.net"))<0)return -7;
  if(gnutls_set_default_priority(tls_sesion)<0)return -8;
  int ret=gnutls_priority_set_direct(tls_sesion,"NORMAL",&txterr);
  if(ret<0){
    switch(ret){
    case GNUTLS_E_INVALID_REQUEST:
      printf("Error tipo %s\n",txterr);
      return -9;
    }
  }
  if(gnutls_credentials_set(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_CRD_CERTIFICATE,xcred)<0)return -10;
  gnutls_session_set_verify_cert(tls_sesion,"blackrook.ddns.net",0);
  //Toma el FD Socket
  gnutls_transport_set_int(tls_sesion,fd);
  gnutls_handshake_set_timeout(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_DEFAULT_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT);
  do{ret=gnutls_handshake(tls_sesion);
  }while(ret<0&&!gnutls_error_is_fatal(ret));
  if(ret<0){
    printf("RET:%d\n",ret);
    gnutls_certificate_type_t type;
    int status;
    switch(ret){
    case GNUTLS_E_CERTIFICATE_VERIFICATION_ERROR:
      type=gnutls_certificate_type_get(tls_sesion);
      status=gnutls_session_get_verify_cert_status(tls_sesion);
      if(gnutls_certificate_verification_status_print(status,type,&out,0)<0)return -255;
      printf("TLS: cert verify output: %s\n",out.data);
      gnutls_free(out.data);
    }
    printf("TLS: Handshake fallado: %s\n",gnutls_strerror(ret));
    return -11;
  }{
    char*desc=gnutls_session_get_desc(tls_sesion);
    printf("TLS: Session info: %s\n",desc);
    gnutls_free(desc);
  }
  //Recibe mensaje
  char msg[16387];long max=16387,nres;
  sleep(4);
  nres=gnutls_record_recv(tls_sesion,msg,max);
  printf("R:%s\n",msg);

  //CIERRA PUERTO
  if(gnutls_bye(tls_sesion,GNUTLS_SHUT_RDWR)<0)printf("TLS: Falla cerrando\n");
  close(fd);
  gnutls_deinit(tls_sesion);
  gnutls_certificate_free_credentials(xcred);
  gnutls_global_deinit();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"... now you need the certificate and the key that was only used on the server side"* - I assume you mean "You need the server's certificate and the key at the client". That's just plain wrong. The client needs its certificate and its private key; its does not need the server's certificate and private key. However, the client needs a certificate to root trust in the server, liek a CA (but not its key). You are doing something wrong in your code, probably due to a misunderstanding or typo.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it, then in that case the examples offered by GnuTLS are wrong.
in that case I must maintain the function gnutls_certificate_set_x509_trust_file .